# GRUB not installed

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (32 Bit, i386) on the second hard disk of a PC using a CD-ROM. The first drive contains Windows XP. It's rather old hardware but the installation apparently worked fine.

After reboot there is no daul boot screen and I am unable to start the new Ubuntu installation.

What went wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: To what HDD did you install the Grub bootloader? sda or sdb ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to alter the boot order of your computer. Open the BIOS configuration and set the second hard disk as the primary boot device.

Comment: Hi, does that mean,, that I can only boot either Windows or Ubuntu? Martin

Comment: No, as your GRUB menu will also include an entry to boot Windows.

Comment: Hi, I think, Grub was not installed at all! Martin

Comment: Try @Cumulus007's suggestion and make the second hard drive (that has Ubuntu) the primary boot device. If grub is installed there, it will give you the choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows (from the first drive). If it boots straight to Ubuntu let us know.

Comment: Or if just booting of the second drive explicitly works, once you're in you can install grub on the other, and leave bios alone.

Comment: Hi, what I wanted to do is to install a dual boot loader, giving the choice to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. It is not ny own pc, but that of a friend. Now I have booted this pc and I'm presently working on this machine. In the Windows Disk Manager of this Machine im am seeing the following hard disk configuration:

Comment: Hi, what I wanted to do is to install a dual boot loader, giving the choice to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. It is not ny own pc, but that of a friend. Now I have booted this pc and I'm presently working on this machine. In the Windows Disk Manager of this Machine im am seeing the following hard disk configuration: 
Disk1: Eisa partition (32MB),  Windows (C: 76GB)
Disk2: D: (10GB), Ubunt (9GB) Free space (54 GB) Swap (1GB)

Comment: Hi, what I wanted to do is to install a dual boot loader, giving the choice to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. Now I have booted this pc and I'm presently working on this machine. In the Windows Disk Manager of this Machine im am seeing the following hard disk configuration: Disk1: Eisa partition (32MB), Windows (C: 76GB) Disk2: D: (10GB), Ubunt (9GB) Free space (54 GB) Swap (1GB) Is there a simple way to install Grub to the disk1 (addressed as sda in Linux) with the option to boot the Linux on sdb ? What I want to avoid is to make a new installation of Ubuntu on sda. Any idea? thanks Martin

Comment: Hi, is it possible to execute grub-install in order to put a boot sector on sda with the choice to boot either Windows on sda or Ubuntu on sdb? thanks Martin

Comment: Have you even tried switching the boot order? Please use our suggestions before asking other questions.